# Which version is python console in gedit 2.30.4?

Tags: python, console

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit and using gedit 2.30.4 - enabling bottom view (ctrl + F9) opens a python console for running .py scripts. Does anyone know which version of python this console is using? 2.7, 3.0, etc.?

Comment: On a side note, 14.10 has been outdated since September 2015 and is no longer receiving important updates like security updates, so you should upgrade. An LTS version like 16.04 is probably best if you don't want to upgrade every six months or so, since LTS versions receive updates for five years.

Comment: Yes, aware that 14.10 is quite old now, and will get to that upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know which version it is, but it is easy to check the version from a [Python interpretor session](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9079062/2072269):

```
import sys; print (sys.version_info)
```

Comment: Thanks - this helped me to answer my own question and is a valuable command to remember. The command tells me that gedit is using version is 2.7.6.